# How to automatically trigger build on pull request in Azure DevOps?

Tags: build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

I have created a build pipeline.

have master, develop and feature/* branches in my Azure repo.

I have created a branch policy to require a build for feature/* branches.

How do I trigger an automatic build on pull request? Or even how do I queue a build manually on the pull request?

I can't see such option on my pull request screen in DevOps.

As far as I know the build policy should appear above *Work Items* on the right hand side. My policy does not appear there and I have no even a possibility to trigger the build manually.

[image: ops]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Or what is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you provided shows that the PR is for the `develop` branch. If you want a PR for `develop` to trigger a build, then set a policy on the `develop` branch.

Branch policies apply to the **target** branch, not the **source** branch.